# Start Streamlabs stream with Python or CMD prompt and monetize it automatically

Tags: python, cmd, youtube

I stream 24/7 with Streamlabs. When restarting my computer I need to manually start the stream. I would like to automate this process with a CMD prompt or with the help of python by just "opening" and then starting the stream. On OBS Studio it seems to be a simple launching parameter

--startstreaming

But on Streamlabs this function seems to not exist (or I do not know it).

Now how should I set it up in order to start the stream automatically? A click function on "Start stream" would help too.

Also: there is no way to automatically monetize a stream with YouTube - I would always have to open my channel and monetize the stream automatically. Can I automate that too? Also here: it would be sufficient to open the browser with the right link and click on the stream and monetize it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I was able to transfer SLOBS to OBS Studio and stream with the following prompt:

```
title obs_stream
:loop
cd C:\Program Files\obs-studio\bin\64bit
taskkill /im obs64.exe /t /f
obs64.exe  --startstreaming
timeout /t 28800
goto loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The [StreamLabs Desktop API](https://stream-labs.github.io/streamlabs-desktop-api-docs/docs/index.html) provides a remote management API for the appication.

The [StreamingService](https://stream-labs.github.io/streamlabs-desktop-api-docs/docs/classes/_streaming_streaming_.streamingservice.html#togglestreaming) allows you to send messages to the app to toggle streaming on and off once the app is launched.

If you want to access it via Python, [PySLOBS](https://pypi.org/project/PySLOBS/) provides a wrapper to make the interface more Pythonic.